# Picture(graphic) and minipage causing error on Beamer

Tags: beamer, diagrams, minipage

I am currently creating a beamer document, and each time I try to insert a minipage and a picture, an error occurs. If I comment out the minipage and picture, it runs fine. I have tried running one at a time, so I know both issues are causing errors.

I have included the basics of the coding, without any scaling, etc... because it's not working even with the bare-bones of the command.

Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}
\begin{center}
\huge{Title}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}
\includegraphics{picture.JPEG}
\caption{link}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`minipage` requires a width argument

```
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
```

or some such width

you have

```
\begin{minipage}
\begin
```

which is the same as

```
\begin{minipage}{\begin}
```

and it will try to interpret `\begin` as a length. Everything after that will be bad.

You could add width arguments to both minipages, but they do not appear to be doing anything useful so simpler would be just to delete them

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{center}
\huge Title
\end{center}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{link}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank-you, I've tried the simplified format above, and it's telling me that I'm missing a $ in the:

Comment: Sorry- Thank-you, I've tried the simplified format above, and it's telling me that I'm missing a $ in the: \begin{figure} area?

Comment: Did you copy exactly the text above into a new file and it gives an error? it should not, I tested it here (texlive 2016)

Comment: I think it was the caption- it was too long. I've shortened it and it's working now.

Comment: @karen being long isn't itself going to generate an error but there could have been  an error in the longer text that you have now deleted.

Comment: Thank-you! It was a link to a website, not sure it makes a difference?

Comment: `_` character ?